Bootstrap Bundle File Does Not Go Automatically After Publish
In my ASP.NET MVC project, I switched from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 5. During this process, I used Bootstrap's bootstrap.bundle.min.js file.
After all the improvements, I realized that this bundle file does not automatically go to the server when we publish to IIS.
When I manually added the file to the server, there was no problem. Does anyone know the reason for this?

Are you referencing a copy from the /js folder or /lib?

Include the file in csproj and it will be deployed, also on the file set Build Action as Content.

Thank you for your quick responses. When I added the relevant references to my csproj file as follows, the files were published.
<Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.bundle.js" />
<Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.bundle.min.js" />

